# Error while using Drop-down - Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, servicenow

> Hi All
>
> Im trying to select a value from drop-down using class_name/xpath
>   but it's not working. Tried using id but found that the id keeps
>   changing. Need assistance on this.

[This is the dropdown where im trying to select short description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkfLd.png)

Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

username = '*****'
password = '*****'

url = 'https://*****.service-now.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

driver.switch_to.frame('gsft_main')
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element_by_id('user_name').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id('user_password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id('sysverb_login').click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
incident = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), 
"Incident")]')))
incident.click()

open = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Open - Unassigned')
open.click()

time.sleep(25)

element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('form-control default-focus-outline')
dropdown.Select(element)
dropdown.select_by_value('short_description')
```

> Below is the element that I copied and got. 
>   **Copy Element:**

```
<select id="d5f43fd407945410af12f2ae7c1ed05c_select" class="form-control default-focus-outline" aria- 
expanded="false"><option value="zztextsearchyy" selected="SELECTED" role="option">for text</option> 
<option value="number" role="option">Number</option><option value="opened_at" 
role="option">Opened</option><option value="short_description" role="option">Short 
description</option><option value="caller_id" role="option">Caller</option><option value="priority" 
role="option">Priority</option><option value="state" role="option">State</option><option 
value="category" role="option">Category</option><option value="assignment_group" 
role="option">Assignment group</option><option value="assigned_to" role="option">Assigned to</option> 
<option value="sys_updated_on" role="option">Updated</option><option value="sys_updated_by" 
role="option">Updated by</option></select>
```

**By xpath:**

```
//*[@id="d5f43fd407945410af12f2ae7c1ed05c_select"]
```

> Gives me the below error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49915/devtools/browser/30b98d3d-0779-4d85-86bc-9af3a24726a2
[7012:3772:0417/104241.308:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 39, in <module>
    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('form-control default-focus-outline')
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in 
find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in 
find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in 
check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate 
element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".form-control default-focus-outline"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.113)
```

> The above message has two different errors:
>
> 1) [7012:3772:0417/104241.308:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)]
>   XXX Init()
>
> 2) Unable to locate 
>       element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".form-control default-focus-outline"}
>
> Need help on how do I resolve these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try with WebDriverWait to resolve your issue. If you are still facing issue then check if your element is present within iframe

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='form-control default-focus-outline']/option[text()='Short description']")))
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

**Working solution :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chrome_options)
username = '********'
password = '********'


url = 'https://*******.service-now.com/'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'gsft_main')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_name"))).send_keys(username)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_password"))).send_keys(password)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "sysverb_login"))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='filter']"))).send_keys("Incident")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sn-widget-list-title ng-binding'][contains(text(),'Open - Unassigned')]"))).click()

iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'gsft_main')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
print wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h2[contains(@class,'navbar-title list_title')]"))).text

element=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='input-group-addon input-group-select']//select")))
element=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='input-group-addon input-group-select']//select")))
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option in all_options:
    print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("value"))
    option.click()
select = Select(element)
select.select_by_visible_text("Short description")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212148/discussion-on-answer-by-dipak-bachhav-error-while-using-drop-down-python-selen).